# css transition at sticky menu doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with animation at sticky menu. CSS is changed, but not with transition. Anybody has an idea why?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky");
    } else {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky");
    }
});
```

And CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  transition: 0.3 all ease;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3 all ease;
}
.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-fixed-top-sticky {
  background: #601a36;
  height: 80px;
  transition: 0.3 all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3 all ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Which transition isn't working? You can't transition from `auto`...or from a value that isn't stated,

Comment: You should at least add a note why you unaccept answers! @Neuropeptidula

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `unit` behind your timings. `0.3` is not valid, it has to be something like `0.3s` or `300ms`. The `background-color` would work then, but for a `height` transition you need to add a default value in your `.navbar-fixed-top` css class too.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky");
    } else {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky");
    }
});
```

```css
/* --- just for demo --- */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.navbar-fixed-top-sticky {
  line-height: 80px;
}
.content {
  height: 1000px;
}
/* --- just for demo --- */

.navbar-fixed-top {
  height: 20px;                             /* default height */
  transition: 0.3s all ease;                /* added unit */
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease;           /* added unit */
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;        /* added unit */
}
.navbar-fixed-top-sticky {
  background: #601a36;
  height: 80px;
  transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;         /* added unit */
  -moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;    /* added unit */
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out; /* added unit */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-fixed-top">.navbar-fixed-top</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason you have no transition happening is because you don't have an initial property defined for it to transition to. Try this.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
   transition: 0.3s all ease;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;

   background-color: transparent;
   height: 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-fixed-top-sticky {
   background-color: #601a36;
   height: 80px;
}
```

Hope that works!

Comment: I don't think this will work. You forgot (s) in transition-duration.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I did a bit of copy-paste from the OP. Edited.

Comment: But than your answer is still not fully true. The problem is not only that no default is defined. The main problem just was the missing unit ...

Comment: Unless the OP left out the original property values, the `background-color` and `height` would be applied, but would not transition unless it had values for those properties before the class was applied.

Comment: `background` will not need a default.

Answer (score -3):

This should sort it out. Keep the CSS, only exclude the `transition` parts.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
              $('.navbar-fixed-top').addClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky").fadeIn('slow');
           } else {
        $('.navbar-fixed-top').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top-sticky").fadeOut('slow');

    }
         });
```

or you can try adding time units, as you should to your `transitions`:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
       transition: 0.3s all ease;
       -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease;
    }

   .navbar-fixed-top.navbar-fixed-top-sticky {
       background: #601a36;
       height: 80px;
       transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in-out;
    }
```

Comment: Probably because you're making an assumption that a fadeout was required. There is no indication of that in the question.